# Eclipse Mars vs Luna

Tags: eclipse

I noticed eclipse has different versioning system.
It has a number system as well as mars, luna, etc system.

Is it the same? Is Mars same as Eclipse 7 or something ?

Answer (score 4):

Mars and Luna are codenames. Releases are not only called by a number, but also by codenames:

```
Eclipse 3.7 = Indigo
Eclipse 4.2 = Juno
Eclipse 4.3 = Kepler
Eclipse 4.4 = Luna
Eclipse 4.5 = Mars
```

Comment: Be careful with this overly simplified explanation. The version numbers listed here are only for the base platform project, but each code named release includes dozens of projects, all at different version numbers.

Comment: You can even check the whole release table from [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Simultaneous_Release)

Answer (score 3):

The "code names" (Luna, Mars, Neon, Oxygen, etc) are for the yearly simultaneous release of numerous Eclipse projects and packages of them. Keep in mind that Eclipse is not just an IDE, it's a platform and a whole lot more. Those code names refer to releases of many projects, each of which can have its own version numbering.

The names follow an alphabetic progression, so for example Luna comes before Mars, which comes before Neon, etc. That's how you can easily tell the relative release date of them. You can also read the details at [the wiki page](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Simultaneous_Release).